# Android TableLayout null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm trying to create a TableLayout in Android Studio. At the moment I'm putting the table on the dashboard of the app and straight on to the activity rather than as a fragment.

When I run the app I get a null pointer exception when trying to do anything with the table.

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project as well as restarting Android Studio to no avail. I looked at some other questions on SO which is where I got the code from originally but I can't find anyone who has the same error.

As another question, would I be better to create this in a new fragment instead of straight on to the activity?

Here is the XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_table"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

</TableLayout>
```

And here is the Java class

```
public void drawDashboard(){
        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_table);
        table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < classModuleList.size(); i++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams layout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(layout);

        TextView classText = new TextView(this);
        row.addView(classText);

        TextView moduleText = new TextView(this);
        row.addView(moduleText);

        ImageView isComplete = new ImageView(this);

        for(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : moduleCompleteList.entrySet()){

            if(entry.getKey().equals(classModuleList.get(i))){

                if(moduleCompleteList.get(i) == true){
                    isComplete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_complete);

                } else {
                    isComplete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_white_not_started);
                }
            }
        }

        row.addView(isComplete);

        table.addView(row, i);

    }
```

And here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{teamingenium.ingeniummobileapplication/teamingenium.ingeniummobileapplication.activities.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:     Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableLayout.addView(android.view.View, int)' on a null object reference
    at teamingenium.ingeniummobileapplication.activities.DashboardActivity.drawDashboard(DashboardActivity.java:201)
    at teamingenium.ingeniummobileapplication.activities.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:77)
    performCreate(icicle, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your question but the code you posted doesn't contain all the required information.
Question: In which activity lifecycle callback do you call drawDashboard() ?
Note: It should be called after the activity layout was inflated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the issue. I had the dashboard_table in a separate XML file and hadn't added it to the actual activity yet. Adding a TableLayout to the activity XML solved the problem.